# Issue with ng-repeat in angular.js 1.x

Tags: angularjs

I am using **chosen** (a jquery wrapper over select) and bind the object array with ng-repeat as follows.

**abc.js**

```
var contactArray = [{"Id": 1, "FullName": "speaker test_user 1"},
                    {"Id": 2,"FullName": "speaker test_user 2"},
                    {"Id": 3,"FullName": "speaker test_user 3"}
                   ]
```

**abc.html**

```
<option ng-repeat="option in contactArray" value="{{option.Id}}">{{option.FullName}}</option>
```

When I load the page in the browser then it renders the array as follows.

[image]

It rendered first two records properly but in the last record it rendered key value.

speaker test_user 1
speaker test_user 2
{{option.FullName}}

I don't know why it rendered **{{option.FullName}}** instead of its value. Either this is an issue of choosen or angular it self.

I have seen all issues of choosen in github but no was reported this before.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try ng-repeat="option in contactArray track by $index"

Comment: Nothing happened. Still same issue

Comment: Avoid using jQuery plugins with Angular. Chosen is probably executed before Angular gets to render the options. Try implementing it with Angular Chosen directive instead.

Comment: Have you tried assigning contactArray to $scope instead of javascript var and then ng-repeating it?